# Tell, Seek Methods

Tags: python, python-3.x

Use seek() and read() methods to retrieve a hidden code from a list of indexes.

This is the example of the code behaviour:

```
>>>getCode("Da Vinci Code.txt", [4, 992, -26, 1242, 332])
'sofia'
```

```
def getCode(filename, indexes): 
    f=open(filename,'w')
    str=''
    for x in indexes:
        f.seek(x)
        str=str+f.read(x)
    return str
    f.close()
```

I got error while running my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Code", line 7, in getCode
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~pyschools2/888.418298200144529338/gaefile.py", line 223, in seek
raise IOError("Invalid argument")
IOError: Invalid argument
```

Comment: This seems like a logical approach. The negative value could be causing the issue. You may have to maintain a relative index (seek forward 4, then forward 992 more, then back 26, etc). If you provide the file you are seeking through you will receive more help.

Comment: It seems like you should be using `read(1)` to get the character otherwise you are doing unreasonable things like `read(-26)`. You probably also need the second argument to `seek` to indicate where to start the seek.

Comment: @CaitLANJenner function call is just an example. I need to write the code for any file that has been given. Mark Meyer read(-26) means read the line from the end of the file backward and its like encrypted code to find the hidden letter in different position.

Answer (score 0):

The functions `file.seek()` and `file.read()` don't seem to support negative arguments.

You could change your code to this

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for i in [5, 1, 99, 2, 5]:
        f.seek(i, 0)        # offset 'i' chars starting at position 0 each time
        c = f.read(1)       # read only 1 char
        print(i, repr(c))
```

and only use positive numbers. You will need to change  your indexes for this version of code to work.